# Any framework can generate forms from database schema?

Tags: frameworks, code-generation

As titled, in any language. Just do not want to miss any great framework.

- CakePHP - scaffolding
- django
- web2py

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Dynamic Data with ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata)?  It's very much like scaffolding in CakePHP, which is, in turn, very much like Ruby on Rails scaffolding.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on Rails and Grails can generate CRUD with their scaffolding.

Answer (score -1):

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSTookit.html) is a program analysis and transformation engine that is usable on many languages, including SQL, Java, C#, PHP, C++, ...

We have used it specifically to automatically construct the data access layer generation in C# (specificially NHibernate) from SQL DDL.  Generating screens (HTML pages, etc.) to match would be pretty easy.